# Is pull to refresh customizable in IOS6 Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6

Is pull to refresh customizable in IOS6 Xcode? I want something similar to the jasmine app or the new twitter music pull to refresh. I think I should start with the UIrefreshcontrol.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3x1GtRpRm4g) explains what I'm asking for. There seems to be no tutorial or any info on how to control it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great open source customisable pullToRefresh control:
https://github.com/soffes/sspulltorefresh

**EDIT**

The `UIRefreshControl` only supports to change the color tint. You can find more in the Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference)